# SQL Server : how to convert this string to date time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have been querying for a bit, but I still face occasional challenges. I have a SQL Server 2014 database, I'm pulling a specific column which is supposed to hold a datetime value, but instead it has this horrible gibberish which comes in as a `Varchar(2000)`:

```
0:2018061503410000:0.000000:35:0
```

I need to convert this to show a real datetime, like `6-15-2018 03:41 AM` or even `2018-6-15 3:41`

So far I have been able to convert it to this: `201806150341`.

By using this SQL statement:

```
left(replace(o.dsply_val, '0:', ''), 12) as RRT_Arrival_Time1
```

But after I export it to Excel, I am still having a hard time either masking it to show as a date or anything. Excel wants to read it as a number, but when I convert to datetime, it doesn't read it right.

Any help on this would be very appreciated. I already have the 25 data points for my report, but this one is kicking my butt :)

Thanks everyone.

Edward

Comment: How exactly are you exporting it to Excel? If it's going via a string e.g. CSV then Excel ought to parse the 2018-06-15 03:41 format fine, so you could do a little string manipulation in SQL to build that, or parse into a date and reformat to get that form. You could probably also do the date subtraction to get it into Excel's native days-since-X format too.

Comment: I simply copied my results to clipboard and pasted on to a spreadsheet.  It set up that field as general, with the exponent, so I then formatted field to number, so my long string shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the conversion with some substring and stuffing and then casting to a datetime. ie:

```
select cast(stuff(stuff(substring(o.dsply_val,3,12),11,0,':'),9,0,' ') as datetime) as RRT_Arrival_Time1 
from myTable o;
```

Here what we do is, get a substring of it to extract 201806150341 part first, then stuffing a : and a space so it becomes '20180615 03:41' which we can simply cast to a datetime.

HTH

Comment: I tell you, everytime I post a question, which is rare, and I get an answer like this, I want to cry with joy.  Thank you for teaching me something new and for the explanation Cetin.  You Rock!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can try to `convert()` the string you've already extracted as a `bigint`, use `format()` to make a more common datetime expression of it and `convert()` this to a `datetime`.

```
convert(datetime,
        format(convert(bigint,
                       left(replace(o.dsply_val,
                                    '0:',
                                    ''),
                            12)),
               '0000-00-00 00:00')
        +
        ':00',
        120)
```

Comment: @CetinBasoz: True, documentation says starting with 2012. Hmm, in the OP text they say SQL Server 2014 but now that you mention it, I realize the tag says 2008...

Comment: thank you so much sticky bit.  I was able to get the problem solved with a previous answer, but this is also a great way.  Thanks for the knowledge.